# TypeError: arrayal[i] is undefined but it is defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, indexof

I have an array which i created like this:

```
var gelenveri = document.getElementById("cakalinput").value;

var arrayal = [];

arrayal = gelenveri.split(" ");
```

I use this arrayal for my function but i get an error (TypeError: arrayal[i] is undefined  but it is defined) at this while statement which is inside in another for loop :

```
while(((!(arrayal[i].indexOf('%') > -1)) || (arrayal[i] != "-") )){

temizarray[j] = temizarray[j] + arrayal[i];
i++;


}
```

when i try to look at typeof(arrayal[i]) it is in string type. I couldn't solve this problem for an hour. Any idea?

This is my whole code:

```
function cakallik() {
    var gelenveri = document.getElementById("cakalinput").value;
    var arrayal = [];
    arrayal = gelenveri.split(" ");
    var uzunluk = arrayal.length;
    var temizarray = [];
    var j = 0;
    var i = 0;

    for (; i < uzunluk;) {
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i]; //ilk satır alındı
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i]; //ikincisatır alındı
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i]; //üçüncü satır alındı
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i]; //dördüncü alındı
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i]; // beşinci alındı
        i++;

        while (arrayal[i] != "-") {
            temizarray[j] = temizarray[j] + arrayal[i];
            i++;
        }

        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        console.log(typeof (arrayal[i]));

        while (((!(arrayal[i].indexOf('%') > -1)) || (arrayal[i] != "-"))) {
            temizarray[j] = temizarray[j] + arrayal[i];
            i++;
        }

        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        temizarray[j] = arrayal[i];
    }

    console.log(temizarray);
}
```

Comment: before while loop check  `if arrayal.length > 0`

Comment: @TamilSelvanC Still you get into that error. you should stop `while`

Comment: I think `i++;` is causing this issue try to put it outside of while loop....

Comment: i got this error even if i try if statement not about while loop i think

Comment: you are all right that was my bad thanks for all

Comment: @capzyel just look at your code and try to guess what is the problem.... Suppose your array has 5 items so 1 condition will run for min `i = more than 5` so by the time for loop ends it will cross its limits and giving you this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrayal[i] is undefined
```

The error message is pretty clear. Although `arrayal` got defined, `arrayal[i]` is not defined because you are trying to access an element which is not presented in that array.

Inshort, your array `arrayal` length is lesser than `i`, you should add a condition in while to check the length if `arrayal` as well.

```
while(arrayal.length < i && ((!(arrayal[i].indexOf('%') > -1)) || (arrayal[i] != "-") )){

temizarray[j] = temizarray[j] + arrayal[i];
i++;


}
```

Comment: but my for loop is that for(;i<arrayal.length;)